# JSON webservice response

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

I want to display the elements of JSON webservice in my web page.here is my service response

```
  {"business":[{
        "businessguid": "http:\/\/www.example.com/uploads/Facebook-ipo.jpg",
        "businessposttitle": "Facebook ipo",
        "omgguid": "http:\/\/www.samplesite.com\/?p=807",
        "omgposttitle":"samplesite title"
    }]}
```

I tried to parse that service with Javascript ,my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
   {
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
     $.getJSON("insiders.php",function(data)
      {
      $.each(data,function(key,value){
      var da ="<div ><a href="+value.businessguid+">"+value.businessposttitle+"</a></div>";
    $(da).appendTo("#data_area");
       });
       }
      );
    return false;
   });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<div id="data_area"></div></body>
```

But its not displaying anything where i am going wrong..??

Comment: The JSON data is invalid. It looks like two concatenated JSON objects. What you want is probably a JSON array containing two JSON objects: `[ { "businessguid": ... }, { ... } ]`.

Comment: yes.I merged the two arrays and then i donne JSON encoding here it is $final_result['posts'] =array_merge($res[0],$res[1]);
      echo json_encode($final_result);

Comment: I guess the problem is on the server side. You'll have to investigate it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$jdata = "http://www.example.com/myservicefile.php"; //Service URL
$content = file_get_contents($jdata);
$resultdiv = json_decode($content, true);
$businessdata=$resultdiv['business'];
foreach ($businessdata as $key => $value)  {

      echo '<span>'.$value[0].'</span></p>';  
         }

       ?>
```